# screen command: C-a C-\ does not work

Tags: linux, macos, gnu-screen

I'm on a mac, and I also tried on Linux too, but the command C-a C-\ does not work for me.

It's supposed to kill all windows and terminate screen.

`C-a C-\     (quit)        Kill all windows and terminate screen.`

Is there another way to kill it?

I also tried `C-a \` which was suggested in #screen on freenode...but that didn't work either.

(Yes, I'm hitting "Ctrl" for 'C' )

Here is my screenrc: 
https://gist.github.com/chovy/42ee1f38f8e5907a46b4

If I remove my .screenrc, it works...but something in my config is blocking it.

Comment: not to ask the stupid question, but you ARE hitting control, and not C, right?

Comment: Yes, I'm hitting Ctrl :)

Comment: just checking the obvious :)  I once spent 2 weeks diagnosing a video card problem before i noticed the DVI cable wasn't plugged in all the way.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/chovy/42ee1f38f8e5907a46b4

Comment: line 284: you're binding the backslash to do nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the link you posted, look at line 284: the backslash has been bound to do nothing.  Remove that overwrite and you should be able to use it to quit.

Answer (score 1):

Although the accepted answer is likely the best answer to your question, the actual question asked was "Is there another way to kill it?"

There are a couple of 'screen' ways to kill a specific screen session from the command line (non-interactively).

1) send a 'quit' command:

```
screen -X -S "sessionname" quit
```

2) send a Ctrl-C to a screen session running a script:

```
screen -X -S "sessionname" stuff "^C"
```

In both cases, you would need to use 'screen -ls' to find the session name of the screen session you want to kill ... if there is only one screen session running, you won't need to specify the -S "sessionname" parameter.